# Template XSLT Resources

Tags: 2010, xslt, branding

I'm beginning to customize a SharePoint blog and noticed that a bulk of customization (at least in terms of web parts) can be done through linked `XSLT` files but I'm struggling on finding resources or documentation on them.

I lucked out being able to find which template ID controls the individual blog post, but what about the comments, or the post listing? Are there any books/sites that go indepth on the included `XSLT` files from the SharePoint directory? I'd like to learn things like what is ok to take out and how to grab associated lists and things of that nature that I haven't been able to yet.

Any books/sites would be helpful, and I'll put up anything here I find as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the internal names of the blog posts (which really is a type of list), you can then use those to construct your own xslt file which you can then attach to the blog posts web part.
http://onlinecoder.blogspot.ca/2011/12/customize-blog-posts-in-sharepoint-2010.html